# Cannot access folders

Tags: file-browser, system

[image: error message]

I cannot access folders or files in Blender. I have tried reinstalling Blender several times. Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Can you test it in Administrator Mode again?

Comment: Try downloading the .ZIP version from the downloads page and unzipping it to a USB drive or another location you have access to and running it from there. No need to install.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried in admin mode with the same results. ill download the ZIP and try that. Thanks again.

Comment: the zipped makes no difference in admin or not :(